# returning record count in django restful api

Tags: django, rest, api, paginator

I have a very complex API that accepts different filter fields via POST request. the result is a list of items from the database. The total result set can be thousands of items if the user does not filter good.

The API will be returning only 30 items  but I want to add the total amount of items that satisfied the search conditions. I know that I can add a custom field in the Serializer class to return the count but I don't know how to access the queryset to query for the count().

I am sure there is a simple solution for this which I am missing

Thanks
Eyal

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work but the solution is ugly and I can't believe there is no native support for this in the framework. I must be missing something

```
#querysey has several filters set till now
#save the querysey
queryset_orig = queryset
#add limits
queryset = queryset.filter()[:30]    

serializer = ItemsSerializer(queryset, many=True)

#add total count to the first items only
serializer.data[0]. update ({'count':queryset_orig.count()})
```